# Search core result webpart not displaying "no results matching your search were found" in SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, search, search-results, sharepoint-search

This might be very simple, but since I am new to "Sharepoint Search" I'm not able to figure it out.

Using a "Advanced Search WebPart" I'm performing search. On click of search button, if items are found, then the items are displayed in the "Search core result webpart", but if no items are matching for the performed search, then the "Search core result webpart" is displayed blank, here I need to display a message to the user like "no results matching your search were found".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the xsl of your search core results web part and search it for a Microsoft comment: `<!-- When empty result set is returned from search -->`. Just below that comment there's an xsl template to show the message if no results are found, so maybe you can find the default xsl for core results web part on the internet or just take it from the core results web part with default customization and then compare it with yours. Or you can write your own html to display when there's no results by replacing everything inside that template :)